# Firefox: SEC_ERROR_INADEQUATE_KEY_USAGE

Tags: npm, firefox, certificate

After updating firefox developer edition today I have started getting a weird bug in conjunction with npm. Usually, I get a warning and can click on advanced and just get pass it, but now I get the message

```
Secure Connection Failed

An error occurred during a connection to localhost:9050. Certificate key usage inadequate for attempted operation.

Error code: SEC_ERROR_INADEQUATE_KEY_USAGE
```

I have already researched that a bit and found a lot of articles telling that one should delete the cert9.db and cert_override.txt files in the user profile. That did not help.

Anybody having a good idea how to fix that?

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1867023

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Downgrade to 119.0b9 until the issue is resolved.</strike>

https://download-origin.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/devedition/releases/119.0b9/

Fixed in 121